# Birthday Problem Probability

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, birthday

How would I calculate the probability of atleast 2 people having the same birthday given a group of 3 using counting principles. I know that using P(same bday) = 1 - P(not same bday). I calculated this to be $1- \frac{365!}{(365-3)!365^3}$. Is there a way to find P(same bday) using combinatorics principles only?

Comment: yes of course it's possible!

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes of course it's possible!

**HINT**

start from $365^3$ overall possibilities and then evaluate all the possible favourable cases

**EG**

three distinct birthdays = ${365}\choose3$

same birthdays for three = ${365}\choose1$

etc.

Comment: I'm not sure where to go from here, could you clarify what my initial step should be?

Comment: for each person you can choose 1 day among 365, thus you have to consider $365*365*365=365^3$ overall possibilities

Comment: Would it be 365/365 for the first then 365/365*1/365 for the second? Then divided by 365^3

Comment: the way that I’ve suggested is the classical definition of probability: #fav.cases/#total cases, the #total cases is given by $365^3$

Comment: I hope it's clear to you, if you need some other hint do not hesitate to ask, I'm glad to help you if I can.